# Instance doesn't display at template

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to pass an object to the template but nothing is displayed in it.

```
from app.models import Datacenter

@app.route('/datacenter/<int:id>')
def datacenter(id):
    datacenter = Datacener.query.filter_by(id=id)   
    return render_template('datacenter.html', datacenter=datacenter)
```

**html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ datacenter.name }}</h1>
{{ datacenter.name }}
    <p>{{ datacenter.number }}</p>
    <p>{{ datacenter.place }}</p>
    <p>{{ datacenter.capacity }}</p>
    <p>{{ datacenter.tier }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not displaying a `Datacenter` instance, but instead are displaying a `query`. Try `print(datacenter)` in your python code, and you'll see that it prints an SQL statement instead `SELECT ... FROM...`.

You should add `.first()` to your query, and you'll be good to go.

```
datacenter = Datacenter.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
```

Or...

```
 datacenter = Datacenter.query.get_or_404(id)
```

The last one looks specifically for the right id, and shows an 404 error to the user if said datacenter is not found.